# Getting Min, Max, Sum with a single parallel for loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am trying to get minimum, maximum and sum (for the average) from a large array. I would love to substitute my regular for loop with parallel.for

```
UInt16 tempMin = (UInt16)(Math.Pow(2,mfvm.cameras[openCamIndex].bitDepth) - 1);
UInt16 tempMax = 0;
UInt64 tempSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < acquisition.frameDataShorts.Length; i++)
{
    if (acquisition.frameDataShorts[i] < tempMin)
        tempMin = acquisition.frameDataShorts[i];

    if (acquisition.frameDataShorts[i] > tempMax)
        tempMax = acquisition.frameDataShorts[i];

    tempSum += acquisition.frameDataShorts[i];
}
```

I know how to solve this using Tasks with cutting the array myself. However I would love to learn how to use parallel.for for this. Since as I understand it, it should be able to do this very elegantly.

I found [this tutorial from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx) for calculating the Sum, however I have no idea how to extend it to do all three things (min, max and sum) in a single passage.

Results:
Ok I tried PLINQ solution and I have seen some serious improvements. 
3 passes (Min, Max, Sum) are on my i7 (2x4 Cores) 4x times faster then sequential aproach. However I tried the same code on Xeon (2x8 core) and results are completelly different. Parallel (again 3 passes) are actually twice as slow as sequential aproach (which is like 5x faster then on my i7).

In the end I have separated the array myself with Task Factory and I have slightly better results on all computers.

Comment: Aggregation operations like this don't parallelize particularly well, unless you have *truly* enormous data sets.  You're almost certainly better off using the code that you have.

Comment: Well it is an image matrix so I have from 2 to 6 million values.

Comment: I added a couple test runs for reference, it'd be interesting to see what you finally come out with.

Comment: There can be faster options like using GPU or SIMD instructions, but would require a lot more effort

Comment: @Safiron results may differ because of memory cache size. You may also have a closer look to the Partitioner class to split your array's indexses and perform them in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel, `Min`, `Max` `Sum` and similar operations are aggregations. Since .NET v3.5 you have a handy versions of [`LINQ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx) extension methods which are already providing you the solution:

```
using System.Linq;

var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(s => (uint)s).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(sequence.Sum(s => (double)s));
Console.WriteLine(sequence.Max());
Console.WriteLine(sequence.Min());
```

Though they are declared as the extensions for `IEnumerable`, they have some internal improvements for `IList` and `Array` types, so you **should measure** how your code will work on that types and on `IEnumerable`'s.

In your case this isn't enough, as you clearly do not want to iterate other one array more than one time, so the magic goes here: [`PLINQ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) (a.k.a. `Parallel-LINQ`). You need to add only one method to aggregate your array in parallel:

```
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(s => (uint)s).AsParallel();

Console.WriteLine(sequence.Sum(s => (double)s));
Console.WriteLine(sequence.Max());
Console.WriteLine(sequence.Min());
```

This option add some overhead for synchronization the items, but it do scale well, providing a similar time either for small and big enumerations. From MSDN:

> `PLINQ` is usually the recommended approach whenever you need to apply the parallel aggregation pattern to .NET applications. Its declarative nature makes it less prone to error than other approaches, and its performance on multicore computers is competitive with them.
>
> Implementing parallel aggregation with `PLINQ` doesn't require adding locks in your code. Instead, all the synchronization occurs internally, within `PLINQ`.

However, if you still want to investigate the performance for different types of the operations, you can use the `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForaEach` methods overloads with some aggregation approach, something like this:

```
double[] sequence = ...
object lockObject = new object();
double sum = 0.0d;
  
Parallel.ForEach(
    // The values to be aggregated 
    sequence,

    // The local initial partial result
    () => 0.0d,

    // The loop body
    (x, loopState, partialResult) =>
    {
        return Normalize(x) + partialResult;
    },

    // The final step of each local context            
    (localPartialSum) =>
    {
        // Enforce serial access to single, shared result
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            sum += localPartialSum;
        }
    }
);
return sum;
```

If you need additional partition for your data, you can use a `Partitioner` for the methods:

```
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, sequence.Length);
        
Parallel.ForEach(
    // The input intervals
    rangePartitioner, 
    // same code here);
```

Also `Aggregate` method can be used for the `PLINQ`, with some merge logic
(illustration from MSDN again):

[image]

Useful links:

- [Parallel Aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx)
- [`Enumerable.Min<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408.aspx) method
- [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) method
- [`Enumerable.Max<TSource> (IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632.aspx) method

Comment: Well the PLINQ aproach works nicely for Min and Max even though they are separate loops, they are pretty fast (each is 10x faster then single sequential lool on my 8 thread cpu). However the Sum does not work since the frameDataShorts array is UInt16 therefor the Sum() tries to return UInt16 as well. Which with 2M values will overflow very quickly. I can´t seem to find the way with LINQ to process UInt16 values but return UInt64 result

Comment: Ok changing result type to Int64 works, I all three passes (using PLINQ) run in total 3,5x faster then my sequential algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, you can cast the items to other type, like `Int64`.

Comment: @Sarifon, like this (as mentioned in my answer): `sequence.Sum(s => (UInt64)s)` or simply `sequence.Sum(s => (ulong)s)`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think parallel.for is good fit here but try this out:

```
public class MyArrayHandler {

    public async Task GetMinMaxSum() {
        var myArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);

        var maxTask = Task.Run(() => myArray.Max());
        var minTask = Task.Run(() => myArray.Min());
        var sumTask = Task.Run(() => myArray.Sum());

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(maxTask,
                                         minTask,
                                         sumTask);
        var max = results[0];
        var min = results[1];
        var sum = results[2];
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Just for fun due to the comments regarding performance I took a couple measurements. Also, found this [Fastest way to find sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283099/fastest-way-to-find-max-sum-range-in-int).

@10,000,000 values

GetMinMax: 218ms

GetMinMaxAsync: 308ms

```
public class MinMaxSumTests {

    [Test]
    public async Task GetMinMaxSumAsync() {            
        var myArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(x => (long)x).ToArray();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var maxTask = Task.Run(() => myArray.Max());
        var minTask = Task.Run(() => myArray.Min());
        var sumTask = Task.Run(() => myArray.Sum());

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(maxTask,
                                         minTask,
                                         sumTask);
        var max = results[0];
        var min = results[1];
        var sum = results[2];
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetMinMaxSum() {            
        var myArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(x => (long)x).ToArray();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        long tempMin = 0;
        long tempMax = 0;
        long tempSum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] < tempMin)
                tempMin = myArray[i];

            if (myArray[i] > tempMax)
                tempMax = myArray[i];

            tempSum += myArray[i];
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is surely possible that performance wont be good. I am new to TPL and i finally got the reason to look into this. Thanks for the opinion, i will surely try.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the main issue here is that three different variables are have to be remembered each iteration. You can utilize `Tuple` for this purpose:

```
var lockObject = new object();
var arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();
long total = 0;
var min = arr[0];
var max = arr[0];

Parallel.For(0, arr.Length,
    () => new Tuple<long, int, int>(0, arr[0], arr[0]),
    (i, loop, temp) => new Tuple<long, int, int>(temp.Item1 + arr[i], Math.Min(temp.Item2, arr[i]),
        Math.Max(temp.Item3, arr[i])),
    x =>
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            total += x.Item1;
            min = Math.Min(min, x.Item2);
            max = Math.Max(max, x.Item3);
        }
    }
);
```

I must warn you, though, that this implementation runs about 10x slower (on my machine) than the simple for loop approach you demonstrated in your question, so proceed with caution.

Comment: Probably because you are locking the variables, therefore it basically runs sequentially. I believe solution should not have locks and every parallel task needs to remember the its result ( as shown in MSDN) example, in my case its goung to be free results (min, max, sum) however i am not sure how to do that :-/ I tried tuple parallel for wasnt very happy about it :(

Comment: No, the locking block is executed only once per task, please refer to the `Parallel.For` documentation. It's very different from locking every iteration: on my machine, only 5 tasks are used.